# effectively check if data are masked array and all data are masked True

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I have arrays that are simple `numpy.ndarrays` while other times the same variable may be a masked array.  I'd like to figure out the most effective way to check if there are data in the array and that ALL are not masked

I've got the below to illustrate:

```
data0 = np.ma.array([3,3,3,3,3], mask=[True, True, False, True, True])
data1 = np.ma.array([3,3,3,3,3], mask=[True, True, True, True, True])
data2 = np.array([3,3,3,3,3])
for dataNum, data in enumerate([data0, data1, data2]):
    if (isinstance(data, np.ma.masked_array) and not data.mask.all()) or (isinstance(data,np.ndarray)):
         print('if statement passed data{}'.format(dataNum))
```

but this allows for all 3 to pass.  I assume because a `masked_array` is considered an `ndarray`

`if statement passed data0
if statement passed data1
if statement passed data2`

i'd like for data0 and data2 to pass so I can operate on the data.  Ideally it's something simple too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that avoids the multiple cases by first ensuring that the `data` is masked and then testing the mask (which defaults to `False`):

```py
not np.ma.array(data).mask.all()
```

So for your specific example:

```py
for dataNum, data in enumerate([data0, data1, data2]):
    if not np.ma.array(data).mask.all():
        print('if statement passed data{}'.format(dataNum))
```

gives the results you wanted.

Edit: for reduced overhead you can use `copy=False`:

```py
not np.ma.array(data, copy=False).mask.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out the `np.ma.isMaskedArray` solves this problem:

```
for dataNum, data in enumerate([data0, data1, data2]):
    if (np.ma.isMaskedArray(data) and not data.mask.all()) or not np.ma.isMaskedArray (data):
         print('if statement passed data{}'.format(dataNum))
```

`if statement passed data0
if statement passed data2`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. for all arrays you have `isinstance(data,np.ndarray)` to be True.
2. `not data.mask.all()` looks a typo to me.

This should fix

```py
for dataNum, data in enumerate([data0, data1, data2]):
    if ((isinstance(data, np.ma.masked_array) and  data.mask.all()) or 
        not (isinstance(data, np.ma.masked_array))):
         print('if statement passed data{}'.format(dataNum))
```

Comment: this passes data1 and data 2 not data0 and data2

Comment: It was not clear from first version of question where data numbering was shifted. That's why I wrote point 2.  As long as you add a `not` in front of `data.mask.all()` you have the wished solution.

Comment: agreed, that was a typo on initial question submission, based on modifications before initial submission.